# Mongoose: How to unselect a field & still use it to calculate a virtual

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm learning mongodb & mongoose, and I'm trying to make a projects/tasks app
this is the ProjectModel:

```
    const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
        grp: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
        tasks: {
            type: [taskSchema],
        },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    },
    {
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    }
);

projectSchema.virtual('tasksCount').get(function () {
    return this.tasks.length;
});
```

And when requesting the data, this runs :

```
getAllProjects = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = await Project.find().select({tasks: -1});
        const projects = query.;

        console.log(projects);

        res.status(200).send({
            status: 'sucess',
            data: {
                projects,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({
            status: 'fail',
            msg: `error info : ${error}`,
        });
    }
};
```

**The problem is** : I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
Its coming from the virtual property ('tasksCount'), So it seems when I unselect the ('tasks') property the virtual one can't be calculated, I hope someone have a way to unselect 'tasks' and still be able to send 'tasksCount'.

Answer (score -1):

**You can follow this code**

```
 const query = await Project.find().select("-tasks");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.